# How to display post code on category page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to display the user input code, and display it on the web as the original code.

```
<?php #code... ?>
```

Any help is very valuable to me. Sorry for my bad English. Thank you!

Comment: what means POST code? Like HTML?

Comment: Yes!
I tried using <pre> <code> // user code </code> </pr>

Comment: What are you trying to do? How are `js`, `css`, and `php` involved? Seems like just an HTML question

Answer (score 1):

use `<code>you can raw html codes here</code>`
I hope it helps you